# AtomicInteger variables in lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, vert.x

I have an AtomicInteger variable declared as an instance variable like this:

```
public class Test_class {  
    AtomicInteger status_flag = new AtomicInteger(1);  
    public Test_class() {  
    }  
    ...
```

In the code I am using this variable in a for loop and inside the for loop I   have a lambda expression which updates this variable. The code goes like this

```
public void some_class_func () {  
...

for (int i=0; i< 10 && status_flag.get() == 1; i++) {  
    ...
    dummy_func(x, test_lambda -> {  
        ...
        if (some error occurs) {
            status_flag.set(0);
        }
        ...
    });
}//END for
}//END func
```

Is this a correct way to do this to be sure that there won't be any concurrency issues? If a new thread is spawned for each i in the lambda expression, can I be sure that using AtomicInteger will make sure that the for loop will read the correct status_flag value?

Thank you for all the help.

EDIT: I am using Vert.x Framework which uses asynchronous programming.

Comment: do you need any copmpareAndSet operations? if not a volatile boolean may be sufficient. or a non-volatile one if only one thread accesses it.

Comment: Why not `AtomicBoolean`?

Comment: @TagirValeev unless you actually need the operations provided by the `Atomic*` classes a volatile field has a lower memory footprint and fewer indirections.

Answer (score 2):

No threads will be automatically spawned when you do any of the following:

1. create a lambda;
2. pass it to a method;
3. call a method of the functional interface implemented by the lambda.

Since the code you have presented in no way implies that the lambda will be called from another thread (you haven't provided any real API calls), there is no indication that you are facing a concurrency issue.

Comment: Hi Marko..I am using Vert.x framework which uses asynchronous programming. So the lambda is processed as a separate thread. If so, is this code still safe?

Comment: `AtomicInteger` is thread-safe. However, without more details it is impossible to tell whether it's truly needed. "Being processed in another thread" is not enough info to be conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are explicitly creating your own threads (which you shouldn't do in `Vertx`), then you will have no problem.

From the [Vertx docs](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticle_types)

> "...This means you can write all the code in your application as single
>   threaded and let Vert.x worrying about the threading and scaling. No
>   more worrying about synchronized and volatile any more, and you also
>   avoid many other cases of race conditions and deadlock so prevalent
>   when doing hand-rolled 'traditional' multi-threaded application
>   development."

The only exception to this is if you are using a `multi-threaded worker verticle`, which you most likely aren't and most likely don't need to.

If you are spawning a new thread in your method, you need to ask yourself why? This is almost always undesired in `Vert.x`. If you need some form of `parallelism`, consider sending your "jobs" to the `EventBus` and have another `Verticle` process those - setting the [number of instances](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_run_verticles) of job processing `verticles` to the number of parallel processes you'd like to run.